# Python Slack Bot Dialog - Trouble Connecting

Tags: python, slack, slack-api, slack-commands, slack-dialog

I'm starting to use the Slack API with Python.

So far I was able to connect it and send messages just fine.

I want to create a dialog option so users can input variables and I'm able to do it but when I try to submit the dialog, an error appears saying:
We had some trouble connecting. Try again?

[image: slack bot fail]

Here's the code:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
def message_actions():
    data = request.form
    user_id = data.get('user_id')
    client.api_call(api_method="dialog.open",
                    json={"trigger_id": data.get("trigger_id"),
                          "dialog": {
                        "title": "Request a coffee",
                        "submit_label": "Submit",
                        "callback_id": user_id + "coffee_order_form",
                        "elements": [{
                            "label": "Coffee Type",
                            "type": "select",
                            "name": "meal_preferences",
                            "placeholder": "Select a drink",
                            "options": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Cappuccino",
                                    "value": "cappuccino"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Latte",
                                    "value": "latte"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Pour Over",
                                    "value": "pour_over"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Cold Brew",
                                    "value": "cold_brew"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                        ]
                    }}
                    )

    return make_response("", 200)
```

Comment: I've also tried with a 204 response and still the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing us any of the code that is supposed to *handle* the submission of the modal, only the code that creates it.

When the user submits the modal, your app will need to handle a [view_submission event](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#interactions)

I'm not sure if you are using bolt, but you can see an example of how view_submissions are handled with slack bolt [here](https://slack.dev/bolt-python/concepts#view_submissions)

You'll need to acknowledge the submission within 3 seconds. A simple 200 will do